# Remove each image inside of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="idhere">
<span>

<span><img src="link"></img></span>
<span><img src="link2"></img></span>
<span><img src="link3"></img></span>
<span><img src="link4"></img></span>
<span><img src="link5"></img></span>

</span>
</div>
```

I have this code here and I'm trying to remove each img tag and I can't find out how to do such a simple task.

You can use either jQuery or javascript to answer.

Comment: Please post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1.

`<img>` Tag does not need a Separate Closing `</img>` so start by fixing that:

```
<span> <img src="link"/> </span>
```

## 2.

You should look for `.find('img').remove()`

http://api.jquery.com/find/
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

In your case would be like:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){

  $('#idhere').find('img').remove();

});
```

where `$('#idhere').find('img')` performs faster than `$('#idhere img')`. Up to you.

Comment: Yeah I wrote that quickly I forgot :P

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is what you're looking for (based on the title):

```
$("#idhere span > img").remove();
```

If you want to remove *all* `<img>` tags from the page (as it seems based on the text of your question), use this instead:

```
$("img").remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#idhere > span > span > img').remove();
```

(shorter selectors are available, e.g. `#idhere img` - the one above is most specific and can't match any other element by mistake)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#idhere span > img").remove();
```